# How to make custom UIView properties disappear as soon as they exit the boundaries of the view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, uiview

I have a custom UIView that has a few properties like UIButtons and UITextFields. I am animating these to go left and right using `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {}` and am simply changing the constraints in the closure to move the properties to their respective positions. These positions are often outside of the view, because I want them to disappear. Is there someway that I can keep the animations, but once the properties begin cross the boundary of the custom UIView, they disappear instead of showing up outside the UIView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be clearer if you called them **subviews**.

Anyway, based on your comment, it sounds like you want to set the superview's [`clipsToBounds`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622415-clipstobounds) to `true`. Then any portion of a subview that is outside it's superview's bounds will not be visible.

You can set `clipsToBounds` programmatically, or in the view's Attributes inspector in your xib or storyboard.

Comment: I don’t want to remove the sub view though, I just want it to disappear as it crosses the line. Because I am essentially constraining the subviews outside of the UIview to make appear as thought it is animating to the right or left, off of the uiview

Comment: I've rewritten my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thank you! When I added ```clipsToBounds=true``` in init, it did not work; however, when I added ```self.clipsToBounds=true``` in the ```UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {}``` closure, it works perfect!